# Disable popup about using higher Java runtime for applet

Tags: java, applet, runtime

We are running a java applet and are specifying the java runtime version that we want the applet to use but if the user have a higher version installed they will get a question if they would like to use the higher version instead to load the applet.

Is there a way to disable this question?
We want to do this because we are relaying on changes done in the configuration of the specific version of the java runtime.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168706/how-do-you-specify-a-particular-jre-for-a-browser-applet